# Export group events to a external calendar?

Tags: facebook, export, icalendar, webcal

I have a group on Facebook with a couple of scheduled events. I like to automatically update a website with the same event information. I was thinking about using ical/webcal.

Going to the event and choose 'export event' like in this post https://www.facebook.com/help/152652248136178 my own calender is exported.

Is there a URL for the group events? If not, is there an other way to do this?

regards Anders

Answer (score 0):

There is a Facebook ID for each group you can use to plug into the calendar URL. You can find it most easily with a few tools online, like this one: http://findmyfacebookid.com/

I wasn't able to just export a group's events, however. There's a freemium service that does it at wallflux.com, but I don't know how they manage it.